# Having problems reading/writing the php://temp stream

Tags: php, stream

I'm having trouble with reading and writing the `php://temp` stream in PHP 5.3.2

I basically have:

```
file_put_contents('php://temp/test', 'test');
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://temp/test'));
```

The only output I get is `string(0) ""`

Shouldn't I get my 'test' back?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`php://temp` is not a *file path*, it's a pseudo protocol that always creates a new random temp file when used. The `/test` is actually being ignored entirely. The only extra "arguments" the `php://temp` wrapper accepts is `/maxmemory:n`. You need to keep a file handle around to the opened temp stream, or it will be discarded:

```
$tmp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($tmp, 'test');
rewind($tmp);
fpassthru($tmp);
fclose($tmp);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect1-wrappers.php-examples

Comment: Found what I needed - using vfsStream

Comment: Why then the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-put-contents-notes) stated that `file_put_contents()` can accept the url wrappers just like `fopen()`

Comment: @Accountantم …‽ ‍♂️ It *can* perfectly fine. Just this particular wrapper behaves in a very specific way. There are others which work just fine with it. The manual doesn’t say that *every* wrapper makes sense to use with `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @deceze *'Just this particular wrapper behaves in a very specific way'* Yes, I finally found a [note](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#example-348) in the manual that used exactly the same code example in the question and explains that `php://temp` and `php://memory` are not reusable. I guess they mean once `file_put_contents()` closes the stream internally, I can't get it again by `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 12):

Each time, when you use fopen to get handler, content of php://temp will be flushed. Use rewind() and stream_get_contents() to get content. Or, use normal cachers, like APC or memcache :)

Comment: As a side note, you can `rewind` implicitly with `stream_get_contents($stream, -1, 0)`. That will read the entire stream from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a documented small note, that explains why

[Example 5 at the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#example-348) used almost your exact same code sample and says

> php://memory and php://temp are not reusable, i.e. after the streams
>   have been closed there is no way to refer to them again.
>
> ```
> file_put_contents('php://memory', 'PHP');
> echo file_get_contents('php://memory'); // prints nothing
> ```

I guess this means that `file_put_contents()` closes the stream internally, which makes `file_get_contents()` unable to recover the data in the stream again

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but in addition to @OZ_'s answer, i just discovered that 'fread' works too, after you rewind.

```
$handle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

fwrite($handle, 'I am freaking awesome');

fread($handle); // returns '';

rewind($handle); // resets the position of pointer

fread($handle, fstat($handle)['size']); // I am freaking awesome
```